# How to get value from a cell in sfdatagrid? Xamarin Android with Syncfusion

Tags: xamarin.android, cell, syncfusion

I try with this code, but not working, maybe this code is for Xamarin Forms

```
private void OnGetCellValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var column in dataGrid.Columns)
            {
                if (column.MappingName == "CustomerID")
                {
                    var rowData = dataGrid.GetRecordAtRowIndex(2);
                    cellValue = dataGrid.GetCellValue(rowData, column.MappingName) as String;
                }
            }
            string value = cellValue.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

We have checked your code snippet and you are trying to convert object to string (SfDataGrid.GetCellValue method returns object) using as so values not convert to string. You can achieve your requirement by converting the value using ToString method, please refer the below code example:

private void OnGetCellValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
string cellValue = null;
foreach (var column in sfGrid.Columns)
{
    if (column.MappingName == "CustomerID")
    {
        var rowData = sfGrid.GetRecordAtRowIndex(2);
        cellValue = sfGrid.GetCellValue(rowData, column.MappingName).ToString();
    }
}
string value = cellValue; }
```

Regards,

Ashok